# How does bufferedreader readline work?

Tags: java

if you have something like this

```
FileReader fileReader = 
            new FileReader(fileName);


BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
            new BufferedReader(fileReader);

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Why does bufferedeader.readline() read the next line after the first one? What's confusing to me is that there isn't a readnextline method and I don't understand why readline would continue reading the rest of the file instead of looping the first line infinitely.

Comment: It does this so it's easier to read the entire file.

Comment: According to the second part of your question: (usually) reading from a stream (or reader) actually removes the characters from the stream. You can read each byte or character only once.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite this to:

```
line = bufferedReader.readLine()
while (line != null) {
  ... print ...
  line = bufferedReader.readLine();
```

That should answer you question ... 
(the point being the fact that readLine(); well, reads ONE line; after the other; and returns null if there wasnt any more line to read)